# Script to remove text selection restriction from a website

Tags: javascript, unbind

So there are a [site1](http://kokizzu.blogspot.com/) and [site2](http://www.cerpen.co.id/post_133094.html) that disables `right click` and `mouse selection` using this script:

```
document.body.oncopy = function(e){
    if (window.clipboardData) window.clipboardData.clearData();
    return false;
};    
document.body.onselectstart = function(e){ return false; };    
document.oncontextmenu = function () { return false; }
```

I've tried to remove the selection restriction using this command:

```
// works for site1 and site2
document.oncontextmenu = null 
// not working for site2
document.body.onselectstart = null
document.body.oncopy = null
$(document).unbind();
$(document.body).unbind();
```

but the selection restriction not removed for `site2`, how to remove those events from Chrome's javascript console?

Comment: I just ran `document.oncontextmenu = null` in Google Chrome console it works, now `right click` is working, what version of Chrome you are using

Comment: Yes, I have edited the question, the selection restriction is the one that failed to be removed from `site2`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked it seems they are using css to `disable` the selection

```css
.noselect {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<p>
  I am Selectable text.
</p>
<p class="noselect">
  You can't select me ! give it a try.... told you!
</p>
```

Comment: btw, what the default value of those `css` property? `all` or `text`